# Flexible Quilt View using RecyclerView and LayoutManager for Android

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview, quiltview

I'm looking for a gapless flexible quilt view using RecyclerView and LayoutManager for android.

What I expect:

- Dynamic cell sizes. No predefined/hardcoded sizes for predefined/hardcoded positions.
- Gapless. Fill all empty spaces with cells that fit.
- Make use of RecyclerView and LayoutManager

There is one for iOS which is just perfect, but I haven't found any for android.
https://github.com/bryceredd/RFQuiltLayout

### Known "quilt" views for Android

https://github.com/jacobmoncur/QuiltViewLibrary - no RecyclerView, no dynamic sizes, predefined positions.

Anyone know any other quilt view libraries?